# Cakephp 2.x and Jquery : Undefined variable: posts

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have tried to call a view from another view using jquery and I've got an undefined variable and many others errors.

Let me explain

in my **AppController** , I added,  Js to use jquery

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Js');  }
```

in my layout, default.ctp file, I added 2 lines

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
```

and `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('cache'=>TRUE));`  as last line of head block

my add action of my PostsController file , I add the components

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

and in my add action,  I use,

`$this->render('index','ajax');`    if the call is an **ajax call.**

It works if the render command reference a div section.

But when I want to render an existing view , in this case index ,  which is a other action of
PostController that point to view.ctp, I got the error undefined variable posts and other errors.

Can you tell me what is missing?

Comment: Can you please explain better? You're trying to call a view from another view? Why? that's terrible practice. And what is the error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First off you should NOT include the JsHelper if you do not intend to use it. You do NOT explicitly need to use the `JsHelper` in order to use jQuery. It is obvious you have no idea how all these things come together and are connected.

You're getting the "posts is not defined error" because (I guess) when you try to render the `index` view you're not setting the `posts` varialbe. I am fairly sure that there is nothing like: `$this->set('posts', $someVariable);`. This error is shown because your `index.ctp` expects to receive a `$posts` variable with all the posts in it. I suspect that this view was also generated via `cake bake`, right? If you want to render it you will need to get the posts and set the variable `posts`.